# How to share common code between many Corona SDK applications?

Tags: ios, mobile, version-control, lua, coronasdk

I'm working on a set of applications, written in Corona SDK, that should share some portions of their code. There will be common classes/methods as well as common scenes.

I don't want to just **copy** those files (because of [DRY](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY)), so a natural question is - how to organize my source code structure so I can still reference the common code in individual projects.

One of the ways that I can think of is to have a separate directory with the common code and *symlink* it to every project, like that:

```
DEV
|
+ -- commons
| 
- -- project1
|  |
|  - (link)commons
|  - class1.lua
|  - main.lua
|
 - -- project2
   |
   - (link)commons
   - main.lua
```

But is this a good way and won't I experience some weird behavior when building such organized projects?

Comment: Copying a file to a new project is not a violation of DRY, which is a wholly unrelated software engineering principle which concerns duplicate code *within* a project. Branching an existing code base to start a new project is par for the course. That said, if these projects that are ongoing in parallel and you want to make sure that updates to the shared code is reflected in all the projects using it, then sharing makes sense. Pointing to a shared directory (via a project file, or symlink) makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Each Corona Application is a separate sandboxed application.

So AFAIK there is no way to share code between applications.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look into using a version control system, and pull the files to each of your projects as needed. Git seems to be popular these days. [GitHub](https://github.com/) might be a good place to start.

**EDIT**

[Corona Project Manager](http://coronaprojectmanager.com/) might do what you want, at a glance it can share resources across projects.